# WooCommerce Membership only show highest membership plan discount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I am looking to get a programmatic way to approach this where if a member has multiple membership plans, that only the highest purchase discount applies. This needs to display on the product page as well as at checkout.

Currently, it seems to stack the purchasing discounts if a user has multiple plans. Does anyone have any idea on how to go about? I have explored the plugin and the docs and nothing mentions a clear way to achieve this. I had a look at if there might be a way to create a variant of a membership plan (parent > child) but no such luck.

The plugin I am currently using is

- https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/woocommerce-memberships/
- https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a simple way of achieving what I need. All you need is to add the following filter into fubctions

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_allow_cumulative_member_discounts', '__return_false' );
```